# Table header disappears when searching through the HTML table with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I've run into some trouble regarding a search function within a php script. The search function is written in javascript and is supposed to loop through the entire table below and pick out the matching content the same time the user types into the search field. The functions search within the 'Beskrivelse' tab. However, when I start typing in the search field, the table header (Username, Beskrivelse, Links, Kommentar, Billede, Rediger) also disappears as it is also a part of the table.

My question is; **how can I keep the header constant while searching through the table rows below the header?** The header is not supposed to go away at any time.

[Table header is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xArtS.png)
[Table header is hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ25N.jpg)

Here's the full code for the php script:

```html
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 3difpensum ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM 3difstortab ORDER BY ID DESC"); // using mysqli_query instead
?>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Homepage</title>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
<style>
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
 }

 .searchfield {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica;
 }

 .addmore {
  background-color: #535b63; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 400px;
 }

 .secondcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 .thirdcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
 }
 .tableview {
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .tableheader {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #535b63;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .tableheader td {
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<div class="container">
 <input type="text" class="searchfield" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Søg efter Beskrivelse...">
</div>
<div class="secondcontainer">
 <a href="add.html" class="addmore">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="thirdcontainer">
 <table width='70%' class="tableview" border=0 id="myTable">
 <tr class="tableheader">
  <td>Username</td>
  <td>Beskrivelse</td>
  <td>Links</td>
  <td>Kommentar</td>
  <td>Billede</td>
  <td>Rediger</td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$res['ejer']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['beskrivelse']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['links']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['kommentar']."</td>";
  echo "<td>"."<img src='".$res['billede']."'></td>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=$res[ID]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?ID=$res[ID]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";
 }
 ?>
 </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: simple solutions: for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++)  -> make it starts at 1, so it skips the table header row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Check this Your issue is resolved

```html
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 3difpensum ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM 3difstortab ORDER BY ID DESC"); // using mysqli_query instead
?>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Homepage</title>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
<style>
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
 }

 .searchfield {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica;
 }

 .addmore {
  background-color: #535b63; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 400px;
 }

 .secondcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 .thirdcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
 }
 .tableview {
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .tableheader {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #535b63;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .tableheader td {
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<div class="container">
 <input type="text" class="searchfield" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Søg efter Beskrivelse...">
</div>
<div class="secondcontainer">
 <a href="add.html" class="addmore">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="thirdcontainer">
 <table width='70%' class="tableview" border=0 id="myTable">
 <tr class="tableheader">
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>Beskrivelse</th>
  <th>Links</td>
  <th>Kommentar</th>
  <th>Billede</th>
  <th>Rediger</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
 //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$res['ejer']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['beskrivelse']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['links']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['kommentar']."</td>";
  echo "<td>"."<img src='".$res['billede']."'></td>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=$res[ID]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?ID=$res[ID]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";
 }
 ?>
 </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___check this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: No time to explain bro